# Drupal core language module, language switcher block

Tags: 8, javascript

Can a preprocess hook convert the default ul of hyperlinks into a drop-down select list? Something like this hook.

```
function THEME_preprocess_links__language_block(&$variables)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the `core/modules/system/templates/links.html.twig` into your theme's templates directory, call it `links--language-block.html.twig`  and in this file adjust the output from the default ul/li structure into a different html structure.

**NOTE:** there is already 3 maybe more modules that convert the language switcher to dropdown [lang_dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown), [dropdown_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropdown_language) and [bootstrap_languages](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_languages).

Comment: Thanks Glorgosk. I want to use the core language switcher because I had a pre process hook to hide languages if that language was not available on the node. But I ended up using the module Language Switcher Dropdown
https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown/releases/8.x-2.0-beta3. And the was a patch available for it that would hide languages.